# How to close a AngularJS accordion when another accordion is opened in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the AngularJS accordion. When I am using multiple accordions like **accordion-1**, **accordion-2**, **accordion-3**, and I click on the first accordion, the accordion opens, and if I click on the second accordion, the second accordion also opens. 
My problem is: How do I make sure that when I open the first accordion, the other accordions close again?

**Here is my code**

```
 <div>
  <button class="accordion"><b>Mens</b>
  </button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion"><b>Womens</b>
  </button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion"><b>Kids</b>
  </button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Here is my css styles**

```
button.accordion {
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 11px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      transition: 0.4s;
      border-left: 5px solid #4d4dff;
    }

    button.accordion.active,
    button.accordion:hover {
      background-color: #d9d9d9;
    }

    div.panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
      opacity: 0;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

    div.panel.show {
      opacity: 1;
      max-height: 500px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using angular, it may be easier to use angular ui bootstrap to achieve this.  There is a directive for the accordion that you can use like this:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Women">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Kids">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

and then you would have a controller that looks something like this:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
});
```

I pulled this pretty much straight from the docs which you can view here:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

There are a lot of options for configuring these accordions but the one that you will be most interested in is the close-others option that I am passing to the accordion.  You'll notice there is a boolean on $scope with a value of true.  This is causing the other panels to collapse when one is open.